# 1000 page book, without pages with odd digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility, number-systems

> In a book of a thousand pages, we rip off those which have numbers with at least one odd digit, i.e. we rip off $768$ and $100$ but we don't rip off $248$.
>
> a. Which page is in the position $100$ after the pages are ripped off?
>
> b. Which position holds the page with the number $888$?

I started writing a generic number in decimal base: $a.10^3+b.10^2+c.10+d$

Then, I know that $a,b,c,d$ have to be even, and $a$ equals $0$.

I made a tree as follows:

[image: I made this tree]

Then I counted until I found the page that holds the $100$ position, knowing that every green circle holds $25$ pages in it. When I found it I read the previous number because there is no page $0$. That gives me the page with the number $686$.

Then with a similar reasoning the page with the number $888$ holds the $124$ position.

So, I have two questions. First, is this right? Second, is there a better way to approach this problem? I feel there must be a more analytical way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the digits you are dealing with are $0,2,4,6,8$ and you are effectively working in base $5$.

So you could write $100_{10}$ in base $5$ and convert it to even decimal digits.

Likewise you can interpret $888_{10}$ as a number in base $5$.

This gives $100_{10}=400_5\equiv 800$ and $888\equiv 444_5 = 124_{10}$

Comment: I follow the idea but I get lost at the conversion. Could you expand it?

Comment: @xtreymer Well for decimal $486$ for example, this converts (halving the digits) to base five $243_5=2*25+4*5+3=73_{10}$. And if I want to find out the 63rd number left, I convert $63$ to $2*25+2*5+3=223_5$ and then double the digits to get the page number $446$.

Comment: I can see it works, but even after a lot of thinking I can't figure out why you double/halve the digits.

Comment: @xtreymer In base $5$ the digits we use are $0,1,2,3,4$. The even digits are $0,2,4,6,8$. We use base five because we are left with five digits after getting rid of the odd ones - and we have two sets of five which each have a natural order. The bijection between these two sets which preserves the order is precisely halving/doubling. If the digits deleted were different - and we were left with eg $0,2,3,5,7$ we would still be able to use base $5$ but would not have such an easy formula for the order-preserving bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Good approach, but small mistake.  Since there is no page $0$, the original page $88$ ends up being the $24$-th position, rather than the $25$-th. Accordingly, page $200$ is on the $25$-th position ... and so page $800$ ends up being in the $100$-th position.  But yes, page $888$ ends up on $124$